# Implementing a random distribution satisfying RandomNumberDistribution concept

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Improving on [this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161953/implementation-of-logarithmic-random-distribution-satisfying-randomnumberdistrib), I provide `logarithmic_distribution` to satisfy the C++ [RandomNumberDistribution concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution) implementing the PDF

```
p(x) = N*(m + k * log(x))
```

with `min <= x <= max`. Parameters are `m`, `k`, `min`, `max`, while `N` is a normalization constant (to be determined from the parameters). Here is the header file

```
// file logarithmic_distribution.h
#ifndef logarithmic_distribution_h
#define logarithmic_distribution_h

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>

namespace my_random {
/**
   random distribution  p(x) = N*(m + k * log(x))   x in [min,max]

   satisfying the RandomNumberDistribution concept, see
   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution
*/
struct logarithmic_distribution
{
    using result_type = double;

    struct param_type  // required by RandomNumberDistribution concept
    {
        using distribution_type = logarithmic_distribution;

        /// constructor throws if pdf is not well defined, in particular if
        /// min < 0, min >= max, or pdf(xmin) < 0.
        param_type(double m, double k, double min, double max);

        param_type(double m=0.0, double k=1.0, double max=2.0)
        : param_type(m,k,1,max) {}

        bool operator== (param_type const&p) const noexcept
        {
            return std::make_tuple(  m(),   k(),   min(),   max()) == 
                   std::make_tuple(p.m(), p.k(), p.min(), p.max());
        }

        bool operator!= (param_type const&p) const noexcept
        { return ! operator==(p); }

        double m() const noexcept
        { return m_m; }

        double k() const noexcept
        { return m_k; }

        double min() const noexcept
        { return m_min; }

        double max() const noexcept
        { return m_max; }

        friend std::ostream&operator<<(std::ostream&, param_type const&);
        friend std::istream&operator>>(std::istream&, param_type&);
      protected:
        double m_m;
        double m_k;
        double m_min, m_max;
    };  // struct my_random::logarithmic_distribution::param_type

  private:
    struct auxiliary  // the actual implementation
    : param_type
    {
        auxiliary(param_type const&) noexcept;

        template<typename Generator>
        result_type operator() (Generator &g) const
        { return sample(m_unif(g)); }

        double pdf(double x) const noexcept;
        double cdf(double x) const noexcept;
        double mean() const noexcept;
        double var() const noexcept;
      private:
        double m_mk;
        double m_alna;
        double m_cdfb, m_icdfb;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> m_unif;
        double aux_pdf(double) const noexcept;
        double aux_cdf(double,double) const noexcept;
        double aux_mean(double) const noexcept;
        double aux_var(double) const noexcept;
        result_type sample(double) const;
    } m_aux;

  public:
    logarithmic_distribution(param_type const&p) noexcept
      : m_aux(p) {}

    logarithmic_distribution(double m, double k, double min, double max)
      : logarithmic_distribution(param_type(m,k,min,max)) {}

    logarithmic_distribution(double m=0.0, double k=1.0, double max=2.0)
      : logarithmic_distribution(param_type(m,k,max)) {}

    double m() const noexcept
    { return m_aux.m(); }

    double k() const noexcept
    { return m_aux.k(); }

    double min() const noexcept
    { return m_aux.min(); }

    double max() const noexcept
    { return m_aux.max(); }

    param_type const& param() const noexcept
    { return m_aux; }

    bool operator==(logarithmic_distribution const&other) const noexcept
    { return param() == other.param(); }

    bool operator!=(logarithmic_distribution const&other) const noexcept
    { return param() != other.param(); }

    void param(param_type const&p)
    { m_aux = auxiliary(p); }

    void reset() const noexcept {}

    friend std::ostream&operator<<(std::ostream&os, logarithmic_distribution const&d)
    { return os << d.param(); }

    friend std::istream&operator>>(std::istream&is, logarithmic_distribution&d)
    {
        param_type p;
        is >> p;
        d.param(p);
        return is;
    }

    template<typename Generator>
    result_type operator() (Generator &g) const
    { return m_aux(g); }

    template<typename Generator>
    result_type operator() (Generator &g, param_type const&p) const
    { return auxiliary(p)(g); }

    double pdf(double x) const
    { return m_aux.pdf(x); }

    double cdf(double x) const
    { return m_aux.cdf(x); }

    double mean() const
    { return m_aux.mean(); }

    double variance() const
    { return m_aux.var(); }
};  // struct my_random::logarithmic_distribution
}   // namespace my_random
#endif // logarithmic_distribution_h
```

And here the source code:

```
// file logarithmic_distribution.cc

#include "logarithmic_distribution.h"
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

namespace my_random {
using namespace std;

logarithmic_distribution::param_type::
    param_type(double m, double k, double min, double max)
  : m_m(m), m_k(k), m_min(min), m_max(max)
{
    if(min <= 0.)
        throw runtime_error("logarithmic pdf: min <= 0");
    if(max <= min)
        throw runtime_error("logarithmic pdf: min >= max");
    if((m+k*log(min)) < 0.)
        throw runtime_error("logarithmic pdf <0 at x=min");
}

logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::auxiliary(param_type const&p) noexcept
  : param_type(p)
  , m_mk   (m_m - m_k)
  , m_alna (m_min * log(m_min) )
  , m_cdfb (m_mk*(m_max-m_min)+m_k*(m_max*log(m_max)-m_alna))
  , m_icdfb(1/m_cdfb)
  , m_unif (0.0,m_cdfb) {}

inline
double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::aux_pdf(double logx) const noexcept
{ return m_m + m_k * logx; }

double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::pdf(double x) const noexcept
{ return m_icdfb * aux_pdf(log(x)); }

inline
double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::aux_cdf(double x, double logx) const noexcept
{ return m_mk * (x-m_min) + m_k * (x*logx - m_alna); }

double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::cdf(double x) const noexcept
{ return m_icdfb * aux_cdf(x,log(x)); }

inline
double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::aux_mean(double x) const noexcept
{ return x*x*(m_m + m_k*(log(x)-0.5)); }

double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::mean() const noexcept
{ return 0.5*( aux_mean(m_max) - aux_mean(m_min) )*m_icdfb; }

inline
double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::aux_var(double x) const noexcept
{ return x*x*x*(m_m + m_k*(log(x)-0.33333333333333333)); }

double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::var() const noexcept
{
    double mom1=mean();
    double mom2=0.33333333333333333*(aux_var(m_max)-aux_var(m_min))*m_icdfb;
    return mom2-mom1*mom1;
}

double logarithmic_distribution::auxiliary::sample(const double C) const
{
    const unsigned max_iterations = 100;
    const double eps = 10*numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
    if(C <= 0) return min();
    if(C >= m_cdfb) return max();

    // find x where cdf(x)=C using bracketed Newton-Raphson (NR)
    double xl = min();
    double xh = max();
    double dxo= xh-xl;
    double dx = dxo;
    double x  = xl+C*dx/m_cdfb;                     // linear interpolation
    double lx = log(x);
    double df = aux_pdf(lx);
    double f  = aux_cdf(x,lx) - C;
    for(unsigned it=0; it!=max_iterations; ++it) {
        double xo = x;
        if((f>0? ((x-xh)*f>df) : ((x-xl)*f<df)) ||  // if NR goes outside of bracket
           (abs(f+f) > abs(dxo*df))) {              // or NR convergence is slow
            dxo= dx;                                //   bisection
            dx = 0.5*(xh-xl);
            x  = xl+dx;
        } else {                                    // otherwise
            dxo= dx;                                //   Newton-Raphson
            dx = f/df;
            x -= dx;
        }
        if((xo<=x && xo>=x) || abs(dx)<=eps*abs(x)) // test for convergence
            return x;
        lx = log(x);
        df = aux_pdf(lx);
        f  = aux_cdf(x,lx) - C;
        if(f<0) xl=x; else xh=x;                    // maintain bracket
    }
    throw runtime_error("logarithmic_distribution: exceeded " +
                        to_string(max_iterations) + " iterations");
}

ostream&operator<<(ostream&os, logarithmic_distribution::param_type const&p)
{
    using ios_base = ostream::ios_base;
    const auto flags = os.flags();
    const auto fill = os.fill();
    const auto prec = os.precision();
    const auto space = os.widen(' ');
    os.flags(ios_base::scientific | ios_base::left);
    os.fill(space);
    os.precision(numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
    os << p.m_m << space
       << p.m_k << space
       << p.m_min << space
       << p.m_max;
    os.flags(flags);
    os.fill(fill);
    os.precision(prec);
    return os;
}

istream&operator>>(istream&is, logarithmic_distribution::param_type &p)
{
    using ios_base = istream::ios_base;
    const auto flags = is.flags();
    is.flags(ios_base::dec | ios_base::skipws);
    is >> p.m_m >> p.m_k >> p.m_min >> p.m_max;
    is.flags(flags);
    return is;
}
} // namespace my_random
```

One particular question I have regards the design of `logarithmic_distribution`, which follows the following pattern

```
struct logarithmic_distribution
{
    struct param_type { ... };
  private:
    struct auxiliary : param_type { /* full implementation */ }
    m_aux;
  public:
    /* functionality implemented using m_aux */
};
```

An alternative would be

```
namespace details {
struct logarithmic_distribution_parameters { ... };
}
struct logarithmic_distribution
  : details::logarithmic_distribution_parameters
{
    using param_type = details::logarithmic_distribution_parameters;
    /* full implementation similar to auxiliary above */
};
```

This avoids the re-direction (which however is fully inlined), but is somewhat arkward to implement (e.g.\ construction is best done using a `setup()` function). I wonder whether there are any principle design considerations that favour this alternative, or whether there is another yet better way.

Answer (score 3):

- I don't advise importing all the names from `std` into your own namespace, even if only in the implementation file.  That's a recipe for confusion and errors - in the worst case, a function added to later standards could be an unambiguously better match at a call site, as [explained on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/a/1453605).
- I think that instead of `std::runtime_error`, it would be better to use the more specific `std::range_error` when out-of-range parameters are passed.
- Perhaps your constant `0.33333333333333333` would be better expressed as

  ```
  constexpr auto one_third = 1.0 / 3.0;
  ```
- Does it make sense to use `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` internally, or would it be better to use `std::uniform_real_distribution<result_type>`, in preparation for making it generic?

I had to fix a bug: because `std::​uniform_real_distribution::​operator()` is unfortunately non-`const`, we have to make `my_random::​logarithmic_distribution::​operator()` and `my_random::​logarithmic_distribution::​auxiliary::​operator()` non-`const`, too.

With that fixed, I made a test program, which generates plausible-looking results:

```
int main()
{
    static constexpr std::size_t bins = 20;
    std::array<std::size_t,bins> histogram{};

    my_random::logarithmic_distribution dist{};

    std::random_device rd{};
    std::minstd_rand gen{rd()};

    for (auto i = 0;  i < 1000000;  ++i) {
        auto const val = dist(gen);
        // store it into the right histogram bin
        auto bin = (val - dist.min()) / (dist.max() - dist.min()) * histogram.size();
        ++histogram[bin];
    }

    auto i = 0;
    for (auto bin: histogram) {
        std::cout << "bin " << i++ << ": " << bin << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

(partial review - I hope to add to this later)